# How to publish an MVC 4 application which has DataAnnotationsExtensions to AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, appharbor

I have a project wich is referencing DataAnnotationsExtensions and DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation, eventhough the path is set to the bin folder, when I try to publish it in AppHarbor it gave me a not found error message.

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): 
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly 
"DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. 
If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. 
[D:\temp\jeb1ouer.ipc\input\Financy.Data\Financy.Data.csproj]
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Do you have the "CopyLocal" property on the reference set to "True"?

Comment: Yes, I have CopyLocal set to "True"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just [install the relevant dll from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions) and use [NuGet package restore to make AppHarbor automatically install it](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor).

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it! The path was referencing the bin folder, but GitHub do not upload the bin folder, so I moved the dlls to the packages folder and everything worked.